# Twilio Voicemail PHP Interface - Will not run on AWS EC2 or Lightsail

Tags: php, html, twilio

I'm attemting to build an web interface to check voicemail left for Twilio numbers. I'm really stumped at this point was would appreciate any hints as to what I've missed. I am new to developement work so I may have very well be overlooking something simple. The code is running on an AWS LAMP VPS.

1) index.php pulls the numbers from my twilio account, with a view details option for each number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sid</th>
                            <th>Friendly Name</th>
                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        // Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
                        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
                        use Twilio\Rest\Client;
                        include("config.php");

                        $client = new Client($__sid, $__token);


                        foreach ($client->incomingPhoneNumbers->read() as $number) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $number->sid;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $number->friendlyName;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $number->phoneNumber;?></td>

                            <td>
                                <a href="getphn_detail.php?sid=<?php echo $number->phoneNumber;?>">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

2) When the details button is clicked the getphn_detail.php should be displaying all the call records with an option to download or delete a voicemail if there is one associated with that call record. I get an error 500, the apache error log is showing the below error. Line 129 is the last line of the file.

[Thu May 17 16:44:07.266066 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2000:tid 140124901693184] [client x.x.x.x:54504] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/getphn_detail.php on line 129\n'

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>
                Showing Details of <?=$_REQUEST["sid"]?>
                <span style="float:right"><a href="index.php">Back</a></span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Callid </th>
                            <th>From </th>
                            <th>To</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Duration</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        // Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
                        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
                        use Twilio\Rest\Client;

                        include("config.php");

                        $client = new Client($__sid,$__token);

                        $phn = $_GET['sid'];
                        $calls= $client->calls->read(
                            array("to" => $phn)
                        );
                        // Loop over the list of calls and echo a property for each one
                        //print_r($calls);


                        $url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings.json";

                        $username="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                        $password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                        $output = curl_exec($ch);
                        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);


                        $data = json_decode($output, true);
                        //print_r($data);
                        $recordings =array();

                        foreach($data['recordings'] as $key1 ) {
                            $recordings[][$key1['call_sid']]=$key1['sid']."~~".$key1['duration'];
                        }




                        foreach ($calls as $call) {

                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $call->sid;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $call->from;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $call->to;?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php $array = json_decode(json_encode($call->startTime), true);
                                echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($array['date']));?>
                            </td>

                            <td><?php echo $call->duration?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php
                                foreach($recordings as $key => $record)
                                {
                                    foreach($record as $key2 => $value)
                                    {
                                        if($key2==$call->sid)
                                        {
                                            $data1=explode("~~",$value);
                                ?>
                                <a href="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings/<?=$data1[0]?>.mp3?Download=true"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Recording (<?=$data1[1]?> Sec)</button></a>
                                <a href="deleterecord.php?id=<?=$data1[0]?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a><BR />&nbsp;<BR />
                                <?
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                                ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of php are you running under?

Comment: It's running on 5.6.33.

Comment: I have just setup an EC2 LAMP instance deployed via Bitnami, php ver 7.1.17. I was hoping that it was a PMP version problem or something with the older deployment of Bitnami LAMP that is available on LightSail. No change on the new EC2 deployment. 

I've also just put everything up on another hosting account I have through ecowebhosting.co.uk and it is working as intended so this may be a quirk with AWS.

Comment: Per the PHP documentation `PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).`. Please ensure that the appropriate `php.ini` value is set to the correct value. If it's not, this could be the cause as your closing curly braces may not be getting processed correctly by PHP.

Comment: Alternatively, in any place where you're using `<?` instead of `<?php`, try using the full `<?php` instead and see if that resolves your problem. If so, then you can reasonably assume that the short opening tags are not enabled and must be enabled explicitly if you wish to use them.

Comment: That was it! I changed the short_open_tag = On but there was no change, after editing the tags from <? to <?php it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: This was the exact reason I was asking about the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify a few things for you, so that you and others might avoid this issue in the future:

- You had an unexpected syntax error
- I took the code in question and ran `php -l filename.php`  Your file validated, so I could say it was not a missing begin or end block or semicolon.
- I also noted, that you were intermixing tag types which isn't a great idea.  I suspected that it was possibly an issue with `short_open_tag = off` however, php has been changed so that the tag `<?=` is available even without [short_open_tag = on](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).  This has been the case since php version 5.4.  With that said, we never got to the point of verification of your short_open_tag setting.

As I'm guessing you know

```
<?= $somevar ?>
```

Is the equivalent of

```
<?php echo somevar; ?>
```

I know that you were using `<?=` and this, depending on version, should not be a problem with the php version you were using. Using just `<?` is a problem, and it seems that is where you had a problem and the parser was confused, but to that point, you were using `<?php`, `<?` and `<?=` which is where lack of consistency ends up causing issues.

When doing a lot of intermixing of PHP and HTML as you were, I understand the attraction of `<?=`, and the support for it by PHP.
I also advocate that if you have chosen to use PHP for its inherent templating capabilities, then also use the [Alternative Syntax for Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).  There is alternative syntax for if, while, for, foreach, and switch.

When intermixing with html, these fit better and are more readable surrounding and intermixing HTML as you are doing.

In reality, short open tags have come to be officially frowned upon, and are now turned off by default, but in most cases where someone has a PHP based application, are not going to conflict with anything or cause problems.  I'm not advising to go against the grain, but just acknowledging the reality.  About the only thing short_open_tag = on causes a problem with is, if you are using PHP to output an xml file and you are intermixing the xml with PHP as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<? //Some php ?>
```

Even that has a simple workaround, but it's an edge case for sure.

In general you could have avoided this issue just by being consistent in your use of tags, and consistency is a good way to improve the overall quality of your code.

My last piece of advice is that with heavy templating, there are a number of well established php template libraries that could help you separate your logic from your output.  In MVC, this would be separating the C(ontrol) from the V(iew) in your case.  Template engines that are worth looking at are Laravel's Blade, Symfony's Twig, Smarty and Plates.

By moving all your markup to a template file the control/logic portions of your code would be concise and simple.  There is still a good deal of logic in your view, since you are doing looping, but all the template engines I listed have features that let you do that looping on data structures, and provide little helpers for manipulating the data.

For example here is a bit of twig template code that loops over an array:

```
<!-- templates/homepage.twig -->
<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>

<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="span4">
            <h2>{{ product }}</h2>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I took that from [a free lesson](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/twig/basics) by the folks at KNPUniversity.  The principle of KNPU is the lead documentation person for the symfony project.  If you like the material the full twig course is reasonably priced, but you will learn quite a lot, including something about the aforementioned alternative control structures just by reading through the material attached to the course page.

Beyond the solution to your configuration problem, I hope that this might help you with refactoring and improving your project and those you embark on in the future.